# Birthday Calculation

Tags: logic, puzzle

“It’s $2019$. Two days ago, I was $15$. Next year, I’ll be $18$,” said Ginger.

For this claim to be true:

(a) when is Ginger's birthday?

(b) on what date did he say this?

Comment: Well You better ask this on Puzzling community

Comment: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89633/today-i-am-20-but-next-year-i-will-turn-22

Answer (score 3):

The date when he said this is January 1. On December 30th he was 15 years old. On December 31st last year (one day ago), he turned 16 . On December 31st this year, he will turn 17. On December 31 next year, he will turn 18.